# Large categories? How is a set of objects/arrows not a set?

Tags: set-theory, category-theory

Good night,

I found there are categories whose objects and arrows aren't sets, called large categories. I understand if each object isn't a set, but the set of all objects should be a set, even if its an infinite one. Is this because of the way a set is defined? I simply can't understand this; I didn't find anything that could clear this, neither here on Wikipedia and other search results in Google (although I must say, I'm not a good googler).

Thanks for understanding, I hope this isn't a stupid question.

Comment: No, the category of all sets, for example, is the most basic category, and the collection of all sets is not a set. The real difference in large categories is that the collection of morphisms between two objects also don't need to be sets. (Note, in category separate from set theory, objects are not sets, they are just objects - a fundamental unit.)

Comment: How come is a collection not a set? What does one have the other doesn't? "Note, in category separate from set theory, objects are not sets, they are just objects - a fundamental unit." - that part I knew. The objects are not sets, but I think the collections of objects are. BTW, this is about category-theory, I added the set-theory tag because I think the answer might depend on the definition of a set itself.

Comment: @JMCF125: [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) is relevant.

Comment: Look up Russell's paradox to find out the problem with talking about the "set of all sets."

Comment: If you haven't seen the concept of a class or any advanced set theory, this definition is certainly not going to make sense to you, however.

Comment: @Zev, well, I searched for "large category", so I didn't get there. And thanks, it is indeed useful for this. I can't see how can there be an entity which is not a member of another entity though (seeing the axiomatization of a proper class in the beginning of the page). Isn't there for all object $a$ a set $A=\{a\}$?

Comment: A "set", just like any other mathematical object, has a rigorous definition, and some collections of objects don't satisfy it. Earlier on in your life, people have probably used the word "set" to mean something very fuzzy, like "class" or "collection" or "bundle", but they were using informal, inaccurate language. For example, the category of sets is a large category, because the objects of that category do not form a set. If they did, then there would be a set containing all sets, and in particular, it would contain itself, which (I think?) is banned in ZF (an axiomatisation of set theory).

Comment: Most importantly, if you don't know all of this stuff already, then it probably won't matter to you yet - you can study category theory assuming all categories are small.

Comment: @Thomas, I do remember that paradox (who could forget the barber paradox?). Do you mean these non-sets/classes I hear about are as sets that can contain themselves? But then what is the way to get around such paradoxes?

Comment: @Billy, "(...) the objects of that category do not form a set". What do they form then? Won't that notion have the same paradoxes as a set in naive set theory?

Comment: They form what we call a "class." There are a lot of things you can do with sets that you can't do with a class. See the above link.

Comment: What link? The class link in Wikipedia? It doesn't refer any class limitations.

Comment: Ah, sorry, in standard set theory, you can do lots of things with sets. You'll have to ask a separate question to find out what you can and can't do with classes.

Comment: If you call them *sets* someone will take its cardinality. Calling it something else is a way to say 'don't'.

Comment: @RGB, what is the problem of taking the cardinality of some collection of objects?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks. I did [so](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442798/collections-that-are-not-sets).

Comment: @Thomas, I deleted it, it turns out I didn't search well. Therefore, I will answer this question as soon as I see and understand all other useful questions that were possible duplicates of the one I made.

Comment: I don't wish to criticise your attitude here, but it might be better for you to instead ask questions like "what *can* I do with sets?". If you don't know why you *can* take the cardinality of a set ("it's obvious" isn't a valid answer), then learn some more set theory. (Informally, maybe this helps: suppose X is a set containing every set. Then X contains every subset of X, so $P(X) \subseteq X$, where P means "power set". But you can prove that (a) for any set Y, $|P(Y)| > |Y|$, (b) for any sets $Z\subseteq Y$, $|Z| \leq |Y|$. Set X = Y, Z = P(X). This is a contradiction.)

Comment: But, of course, to even make sense of my above comment, you need to define 'set', 'cardinality', 'subset' and 'power set' (and prove (a) and (b) and various other technical things). Before you've defined or proven any of these things, we can't meaningfully talk about what sets can and can't do.

Comment: @Billy, then I shall see those questions (see the comment), improve my question, and finally, answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, because of [Russel's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) that appears in naive set theroy, in [ZF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (a standard set theory) no set can countain itself; and "$\text{Sets}$", the category of all sets, could not exist with a set of objects.

Thus, we need a different type of object collection, with different rules: a [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28set_theory%29). ZF doesn't axiomatize classes, they're informal notions, kind of workarounds. But even in ZF they do solve the problem: you can have a class of all sets; this class isn't a set, and as such, it is called a proper class.

For instance, the collection of objects (and, naturally, of arrows) in "$\text{Sets}$" category is a proper class. Categories like this are known as large categories, unlike small categories, whose collections of objects/morphisms are sets. It's not a sea of roses though, classes have other limitations (varying from theory to theory) that sets don't (otherwise, as you might have been thinking, Russel's Paradox would apply to them too, and you'd need multiple types of classes).

Directly answer your question: in no way; it is a proper class. About "Is this because of the way a set is defined?": yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

A set of objects for the category of all sets would be a set of all sets--or at least a set of all ordinals. Such a monster violates the axiom of foundation which is part of ZF. The usual solution--introduced by MacLane--is to work with a set $V$ of 'small sets' which is a model of ZF instead. This is justified because if ZF is consistent, then there is a model that provides such a set of small sets by Gödel's completeness theorem. This set $V$ defines a category of small sets, on top of which mathematicians can construct other categories of small objects. By contrast with the small sets inside of $V$, the sets outside of $V$ are 'large'. So a large category is simply a category whose set of objects is large, like the category of all small sets.